# Count numbers from row in CSV file

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

So i have this csv file and one collumn looks like this:

```
1022
1040
1042
1035
11728
1036
1022
1040
1042
1035
11728
1036
1022
1040
1042
1035
11728
```

Now i need to count how oftend a number occurs. I need this to make a graphic picture with matplotlib. So the graphic will show how much a number occurs (in this situation it's a event id)

so far i only have the code to print that row...

```
my_reader = csv.reader(open(csvpath))
for col in my_reader:
      print col[3]
```

how do i count how often a number in that specific collumn occurs?

Comment: Doesn't look like CSV or indeed a `row` - is your example *actual* data

Comment: The `homework` tag is being removed, please don't use it.

Comment: @JonClements: I think the OP meant 'one column' instead. The code references `row[3]`.

Comment: Your code snippet references `[3]` (the fourth **column**), but you speak about a *specific **row***. Give us an example output based on your example input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a mapping from number to count. The `collections.Counter()` class makes that easiest:

```
import collections

counts = collections.Counter()
for row in my_reader:
    counts[row[3]] += 1
```

Using a `collections.defaultdict` is also an option:

```
counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
for row in my_reader:
    counts[row[3]] += 1
```

or you can use a normal `dict`:

```
counts = {}
for row in my_reader:
    counts[row[3]] = counts.get(row[3], 0) + 1
```

Comment: `counts = collections.Counter(row[3] for row in my_reader)` for those who like one-liners.

Comment: thnx i used one of your codes :) the only thing i needed to do is change the output so i can use it with matplotlib to create a graph. The matplotlib only takes ("1003", 1) and the output of your codes is , '1003' : 1,. i changed it with replace()

Comment: @DT22: Use `counts.items()` to get a sequence of tuples of `(key, count)`.

Comment: While this a good answer when using python I think it is not a good answer for somebody who uses the [scipy ecosystem](http://scipy.github.com/index.html). With numpy/matplotlib/pandas ... you would normally use parsers that return arrays (numpy.loadtxt, numpy.genfromtxt, pandas.read_csv) and try to use vectorized functions (which are not available in the python standard library). Sometimes it feels like scientific python is a different language at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simply dictionary.

```
my_reader = csv.reader(open(csvpath))
my_dict = {}
for row in my_reader:
    try:
        my_dict[row[3]] += 1
    except KeyError:
        my_dict[row[3]] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will count total number in rows, if you want to particular row then use if condition before print statement and check if count==row_number exa: if count==3: and get total numbers.

```
         reader=csv.reader(open("first.csv"))
         count=0;
         for row in reader:
             count+=1
             print "total no in row "+str(count)+" is "+str(len(row))
             for i in row:
                 print i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to read your data, count the values and than plot it. Behind the scenes pandas uses `numpy` and `matplotlib` to achieve this.
`read_csv` and the plotting commands work for multiple columns too.

```
In [29]: df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', names=['my_data']) 

In [30]: counts = df['my_data'].value_counts()

In [31]: counts
Out[31]: 
1022     3
1042     3
1040     3
1035     3
11728    3
1036     2

In [32]: counts.plot(kind='barh')
Out[32]: <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x4f7f510>
```

[image: value_counts]